# How do I programatically read the version of a currently running oclif app?

Tags: oclif

This title says it all: How do I programatically read the version of a currently running oclif command-line app (from within the app)?

Answer (score 1):

Luckily answer was pretty simple:

```
export default class Foo extends Command {

  async run() {
    console.log(this.config.version);
  }
}
```